# How to timeout a refresh page if element not visible

Tags: c#, .net, playwright, playwright-test

I managed to add a script below to refresh the page if an element is not visible using automation script, and this works but I want it to stop refreshing after a period of time e.g 20 seconds or a number of times if the element is not visible so the test will fail and so it doesn't end up infinitely refreshing. Any advise on how to achieve this with an example please or how to amend the code below to make it work?
I tried introducing a timeout to the reloadAsync method but it doesn't accept it.

```
do
{
    await Page.ReloadAsync(); 
}
while (!await Page.IsVisibleAsync("input[name='elementname']")) ;
```

Comment: The documentation suggests it should accept a timeout: https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-page#page-reload

Comment: I m using Page.ReloadAsync(); This doesnt accept any parameter for timeout

Comment: That's not what the documentation I linked to says. The documentation says that it accepts an object that has a `Timeout` property.

Comment: I tried using the default timeout after the load but it never timesout  and just keep refreshing permanently as shown in this code:                                                                                                        await Page.ReloadAsync();
Page.SetDefaultTimeout(5000);

Comment: I've checked and the `ReloadAsync` method definitely does take a `PageReloadOptions` that takes a `Timeout` value.

Comment: So something like: await Page.ReloadAsync(PageReloadOptions: 5000); ?

Comment: No, more like `await Page.ReloadAsync(new PageReloadOptions() { Timeout = 5000 });` if I'm reading the documentation correctly.

Comment: Ok thanks. It still doesnt timeout? It may be because the refresh is happening quickly that it doesnt timeout? this is what i have now:                                                               
   do

            {
                await Page.ReloadAsync(new PageReloadOptions() { Timeout = 5000 });

             }

            while (!await Page.IsVisibleAsync("input[name='element']")) ;

Comment: Any idea how this can be resolved please? thanks